# Permission problems in Symfony2 on Mac OSX using XAMPP

Tags: symfony, xampp

I am using XAMPP on Mac OSX. I followed the Symfony2 instructions to set `app/cache` and `app/logs` permission -

```
rm -rf app/cache/*
rm -rf app/logs/*
sudo chmod +a "_www allow delete,write,append,file_inherit,directory_inherit" app/cache app/logs
sudo chmod +a "`whoami` allow delete,write,append,file_inherit,directory_inherit"
```

Moreover, I also run the `sudo chmod -R 777 app/cache/*` and `sudo chmod -R 777 app/logs/*`

It worked as well. However, when I close the XAMPP and open it again. It always shows the following `RuntimeException`, and I have to set their permission again and again.

> RuntimeException: Failed to write cache file "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Jobeet/app/cache/dev/classes.php".

I don't find anyone have the same problem as me. 
How can I permanently set their permission?

Comment: Your example show the that you are missing the folder names on the second chmod command. Is that how it is was entered in your terminal or just in your example?

Comment: use ACL to make it permanent.

Comment: Hi @hcoat, It is what I used in my terminal. Could you tell me which folder names are missing?

Comment: It should be: sudo chmod +a "\`whoami\` allow delete,write,append,file_inherit,directory_inherit" app/cache app/logs